# Optimizing a Cypher query in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

I have this Cypher query that I have written.

```
MATCH (grade:Grade:`2547`:Transaction WHERE grade.NodeID="2547:12117:000:6839" or grade.NodeID="2547:12117:000:6841" or grade.NodeID="2547:12117:000:6840" or grade.NodeID="2547:12117:000:6843" or grade.NodeID="2547:12117:000:6842" or grade.NodeID="2547:12117:000:6845" or grade.NodeID="2547:12117:000:6844" or grade.NodeID="2547:12117:000:6838")-[vGrade:Version
WHERE vGrade.Status = "1"]->(grade:`2547`:Grade:Transaction)<-[rGrade:Grade
WHERE rGrade.Status = "1"]-(n:User:`2547`:Transaction)
WITH n, grade, vGrade.Document as GradeDocument
MATCH (LegalEntity:LegalEntity:`2547`:Transaction WHERE LegalEntity.NodeID="2547:12106:000:6167" or LegalEntity.NodeID="2547:12106:000:5754")-[vLegalEntity:Version
WHERE vLegalEntity.Status = "1"]->(LegalEntity:`2547`:LegalEntity:Transaction)<-[rLegalEntity:LegalEntity
WHERE rLegalEntity.Status = "1"]-(n:User:`2547`:Transaction)
WITH n, grade, GradeDocument, LegalEntity, LegalEntityDocument
RETURN n, Grade, GradeDocument, LegalEntity, LegalEntityDocument
```

I need to find all those User nodes that are related to a given set of Grade ids and LegalEntity ids. The output of the query is as required. but I would like to know if there is any way that the performance of this query could be improved, as this is one of the queries that I'm generating. But the general structure of all the queries would be like this only. The number of nodeIDs in the MATCH statements in the above query are just an example, the actual number of the nodeIDs could vary, but that is being handled by the code and the resulting structure is same as above. Also, the number of match statements could also increase as per requirement.

[image: Example of how the relationship exists in neo4j]

Currently, the query is taking 10-14 seconds and the output is correct(result has a bit more than 9500 records). Is there any way in which the execution time of the query be decreased?

Comment: I didn't know you could have `WHERE` inside your nodes. What's the difference to having it outside?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should make sure you have an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/) (or [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/#_implications_on_indexes), if appropriate) on the `NodeID` property of the appropriate label(s). This will greatly speed up the queries for nodes with specific `NodeID` values.

   For example, if every `Transaction` node node should have a unique `NodeID` value, create a uniqueness constraint (which will automatically create an index for you) like this:

   ```
   CREATE CONSTRAINT Transaction_NodeID FOR (t:Transaction) REQUIRE t.NodeID IS UNIQUE
   ```
2. When you reuse an already-defined variable, just use its name instead of redefining it to any extent. This simplification can eliminate unnecessary additional work. In your query, `` (grade:`2547`:Grade:Transaction) `` should just be `(grade)`, and `` (LegalEntity:`2547`:LegalEntity:Transaction) ``, should be `(LegalEntity)`.
3. You should pass [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) for the non-static parts of your query. That way, the server will only need to compile your query once, no matter how many times you call it with different parameter values.

   This example shows how to refactor your query to use the parameters $gradeIds and $entIds, each of which must be a list of ids. In addition, this query also attempts to fix a bug in your query, where `LegalEntityDocument` was not defined. And it also fixes item #2, above.

   ```
   MATCH (grade:Grade:`2547`:Transaction)-[vGrade:Version {Status: "1"}]->(grade)<-[:Grade {Status: "1"}]-(n:User:`2547`:Transaction)
   WHERE grade.NodeID IN $gradeIds
   WITH n, grade, vGrade.Document as GradeDocument
   MATCH (LegalEntity:LegalEntity:`2547`:Transaction)-[lGrade:Version {Status: "1"}]->(LegalEntity)<-[:LegalEntity {Status: "1"}]-(n)
   WHERE LegalEntity.NodeID IN $entIds
   RETURN n, Grade, GradeDocument, LegalEntity, lGrade.Document AS LegalEntityDocument
   ```